# Convert range(r) to list of strings of length 2 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, range

I just want to change a list (that I make using range(r)) to a list of strings, but if the length of the string is 1, tack a 0 on the front.
I know how to turn the list into strings using

```
ranger= map(str,range(r))
```

but I want to be able to also change the length of those strings.

Input:

```
r = 12
ranger = range(r)
ranger = magic_function(ranger)
```

Output:

```
print ranger
>>> ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11']
```

And if possible, my final goal is this:
I have a matrix of the form

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

and I want to make a set of strings such that the first 2 characters are the row, the second two are the column and the third two are '01', and have matrix[row,col] of each one of these.
so the above values would look like such:

```
000001    since matrix[0,0] = 1
000101    since matrix[0,1] = 2
000101    since matrix[0,1] = 2
000201
000201
000201
etc
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`string formatting`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) and list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = range(11)
>>> ["{:02d}".format(x) for x in lst]
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
```

or [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> [format(x, '02d') for x in lst]
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
```

Comment: Great use of the format() built-in function with the 2nd example

Answer (score 16):

`zfill` does exactly what you want and doesn't require you to understand an arcane mini-language as with the various types of string formatting. There's a place for that, but this is a simple job with a ready-made built-in tool.

```
ranger = [str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(r)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my take on it:

```
>>> map('{:02}'.format, xrange(12))
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11']
```

For your own enlightenment, try reading about the [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: does this return a map object?

Answer (score 3):

Use string formatting:

```
>>> sr = []
>>> for r in range(11):
...     sr.append('%02i' % r)
... 
>>> sr
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
```

Answer (score 1):

### One liner in Python 3.x

```
>>> ranger =  [f'{i:>02}' for i in range(1, 12)]
>>> print (ranger)

['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11']
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Ashwini Chaudhary's solution, you can use range() within list comprehension:

code:

```
my_list = [format(x, '02d') for x in range(11)]
print(my_list)
```

output:
['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']