# Creating a range of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a range of numbers in this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Ranges': 1-np.arange(0, 1 , 0.1)
})
```

[image]

But the output expected is (in the same column):

```
0.9 - 1
0.8 - 0.9
0.7 - 0.8
0.6 - 0.7
0.5 - 0.6
0.4 - 0.5
0.3 - 0.4
0.2 - 0.3
0.1 - 0.2
0 - 0.1
```

I have tried using these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328442/using-a-for-loop-to-generate-a-string-of-numbers-out-of-a-range),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577797/convert-ranger-to-list-of-strings-of-length-2-in-python),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093829/generating-a-range-of-numbers-as-strings-python) solutions but none of them helps me to get nearer a solution. Any suggestions?

PS: The specific format of the numbers it doesn't matter (could be 1.0 or 1, 0.5 or .5 for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i could understand you needed to make intervals such as "0.9 - 1", here's my suggestion.

```
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'Ranges': [str(x/10) +'-' +str(y/10) for x,y in zip(9- np.arange(1, 10, 1), 10-np.arange(1, 10, 1))]
        })
```

Expected output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation on the shifted Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ranges': 1-np.arange(0, 1 , 0.1)})

s = df['Ranges'].round(2).astype(str)

out = s.shift(-1, fill_value='0.0') + ' - ' + s
```

output:

```
0    0.9 - 1.0
1    0.8 - 0.9
2    0.7 - 0.8
3    0.6 - 0.7
4    0.5 - 0.6
5    0.4 - 0.5
6    0.3 - 0.4
7    0.2 - 0.3
8    0.1 - 0.2
9    0.0 - 0.1
Name: Ranges, dtype: object
```